# Reverse proxy subfolder to subfolder

Tags: azure, dns, reverse-proxy

We have a production website:
example.com (.Net / Hosted on Azure) IP address: 75.75.75.75

we want to publish some pages on our Wordpress website (IP: 85.85.85.85) but be available on our domain:
under here:
example.com/articles

We can do articles.example.com with a DNS A record but we need it to be as a subfolder, not a subdomain. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: DNS is not aware of the paths/folders, you will have to configure this in your webserver (so the answer will depend on which webserver are you using)

Comment: @DusanBajic we are using Azure app service which is a managed IIS. Any tips on how to do it?

Comment: Any more questions? Is this reply helpful?

Answer (score 1):

To deploy Web App to a Sub-folder on Azure App service, you could add the virtual directory on the Azure app service via going to portal > your App Service > Configuration > Path Mappings > Virtual applications and directories. And add the following and click `Save` and restart the App Service.

[image]

Then you could publish your site's content with select Virtual Path and your app service, then you will access your sites with `example.com/test`.
For more information, you could read [this1](https://sajeetharan.com/2020/01/11/deploy-web-app-to-a-sub-folder-on-azure/) and [this2](https://carldesouza.com/configuring-virtual-applications-with-azure-app-services-and-apim/).